# Neo4j Cypher: How to fetch nodes with conditional query on reation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, neo4j, cypher, neo4j.rb

I have two Neo4j Nodes and one relation:

```
class StayPal
  include Neo4j::ActiveNode

  has_many :in, :places, origin: :owner
  has_many :in, :shared_places, rel_class: 'HouseMate'
end

class Place
  include Neo4j::ActiveNode

  has_one :out, :owner, type: :owner_of, model_class: 'StayPal'
  has_many :out, :house_mates, rel_class: 'HouseMate'
end

class HouseMate
  include Neo4j::ActiveRel
  include Enumable

  creates_unique

  from_class 'Place'
  to_class 'StayPal'
  type 'shared_with'

  property :status, default: 0

  enum_attr status: [:pending, :approved, :declined, :cancelled]
end
```

**Objective:** My objective is get places & shared_places of staypal together but the shared places included if they are status == approved

**Query:**

```
Neo4j::Session.current.query
  .match(n: { StayPal: { user_id: 1 } })
  .match('n<-[rel1:`owner_of`]-(result_places:`Place`)')
  .match('n<-[rel2:`shared_with`]-(result_places1:`Place`)')
  .pluck(:result_places1, :result_places)
```

With this I am getting the places and shared places of staypal

But I want shared places where status = 1

Modified Query

```
Neo4j::Session.current.query
  .match(n: { StayPal: { user_id: 1 } })
  .match('n<-[rel1:`owner_of`]-(result_places:`Place`)')
  .match('n<-[rel2:`shared_with`]-result_places1:`Place`)')
  .where('result_places1.status = 1')
  .pluck(:result_places1, :result_places)
```

**But with this I am getting no records**

Some other helping queries

```
Neo4j::Session.current.query
  .match(n: { StayPal: { user_id: 1 } })
  .match('n<-[rel1:`owner_of`]-(result_places:`Place`)')
  .match('n<-[rel2:`shared_with`]-result_places1:`Place`)')
  .where('result_places1.status = 1')
  .pluck(:result_places1)
```

Output:

```
[CypherRelationship 1239]
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the `neo4j-core` Query API, which you can do and which should allow you to get `ActiveNode` and `ActiveRel` objects, but there is a higher level API which is easier:

```
StayPal.where(user_id: 1).places(:place1).shared_places(:places2).pluck(:place1, place2)
```

To do this I assumed that you add this association to `Place`:

```
has_many :both, :shared_places, type: :shared_with
```

Note that I used the singular form for variables.  It's important to remember that when you are matching that it does one match at a time.  Singular variables help us to keep that in context.

Aside from that, though, I think you have a deeper issue that your `HouseMate` relationship is going from a Place to a `StayPal`.  What is your model?  If you want to record two people staying in the same house, you might want to have a new node with a label like `HouseMateGroup` and that node could point to the Place as well as two (or more) StayPals.

**EDIT:**

I think I'm understanding your use case more.  I would probably make the model `(:StayPal)-[:LIVES_IN]->(:Place)<-[:LIVES_IN]-(:StayPal)`

Any given step in that doesn't map to the idea of a "house mate", but you can easily get the housemates by following relationships/associations.  So if you wanted to get housemates you might do:

```
pal = StayPal.find_by(user_id: 1)

pal.places.people
```

That would get you all of the people that are in the places which `user_id: 1` is in.

If you wanted to find all places which have associated people:

```
Place.as(:place1).people.places(:place2).pluck(:place1, :place2)
```

You could even count the number of people that exist in that relationship between places:

```
Place.as(:place1).people(:person).places(:place2).pluck(:place1, :place2, 'count(person)')
```

Comment: (sorry if this answer isn't quite on point, I had to answer very quickly.  You might also drop by our Gitter channel if you have other questions https://gitter.im/neo4jrb/neo4j )

Comment: yes  I need two or more people staying in the same house and one will be the onwer and other persons comes though invitation where we have different status (approve/declied)..........Before add this multiple users in one house I had only one place , one owner kind of functioanlity which already have database.. any help to work with this query ...........I want users its own places as well as shared with him by other owners?

Comment: I am confused `(:StayPal)-[:LIVES_IN]->(:Place)<-[:LIVES_IN]-(:StayPal)` This is good but I have to maintain the invitation system where person's are requested  to share the room .. So I need house Mate relation to do that so ... What is people you are mentioning in the queries??....And  place and owner relation already exists with data in production So just need to add the housemate feature where other users(staypals) are requested to share room

Comment: You could just have another relationship like `(:StayPal)-[:REQUESTED_STAY_IN]->(:Place)` or something like that, right?  Then you could just replaced it with `LIVES_IN` if the request is approved.  But if it's already in production that's trickier, obviously, but 8.0 of the `neo4j` gem does provide migration functionality.  Feel free to ignore my suggestions for labels/relationship types, but does the association chaining syntax make sense?  I'd suggest watching this series: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL5klM3mD6alLUhNTPTbj5a3GBjU7oZN0t